# Add number of week into date

Tags: php, date, strtotime, dayofweek

I want to add no. of week in date. Result should come in date "Y-m-d".

Here, "time_take" is coming from database and this is in no. like 1, 2, 3, 5, 7 etc.

```
  <?php
        $date = $record['Child']['dob'];
        $str = "'+".$Vac['Vac']['time_take']." week'";

        echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($str,strtotime($date)));                
   ?>
```

My result is coming "1970-01-01"

This is the format of date in database.

Help me.

Comment: Do you want week as per the whole year or in specific month?

Comment: What format is the dob in `$record['Child']['dob']`

Comment: I update my question as answer of your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
 $date = "2015-01-01";
 $str = "+".$Vac['Vac']['time_take']." week";
 //echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime("$str",strtotime($date)));
  echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($str,strtotime($date)));
?>
```

**Output:**

```
2015-01-08
```

**Check in online editor. [Click Here](https://eval.in/553414)**

Comment: why minus vote. Please mention. :( Also attached live demo. :(

Comment: The week is also a variable. Using `$str = "+1 week";` does not answer the question

Comment: I have just given idea now user can add it dynamically. I have edited my answer. please check. @RiggsFolly

Comment: I saw and removed the DV

Comment: So you are the spitefull downvoter. That is not a good habit to get into. A DV should be for a good reason and come with an explanation!

Comment: I have not given DV to you. One of mine friend told me u have not use concatination in $num so he has given and then i have tried your answer and given UV. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Did he actually test it. **I did!** Tell him that $variables are automatically expanded when in double quotes. I test almost all of my answers, so as to be **right** rather than **first**

Comment: You might want to test @BrijalSavaliya answer as well, that does not work

Comment: Yes. I have added comment. @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1):

If you keep it simple to start with you can always concatenate the code once its working

```
$dob   = $record['Child']['dob'];
$num   = $Vac['Vac']['time_take'];
$pDate = strtotime("$dob + $num week");
echo date('Y-m-d',$pDate);
```

Comment: So who is giving out Spiteful down votes. Mine always have a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$start_date = $record['Child']['dob'];  
$str =  $Vac['Vac']['time_take'];
$date = strtotime($start_date);
$date = strtotime("+".$str." week", $date);
echo date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

Comment: You need to use $str = "+".$Vac['Vac']['time_take']." week";. over here.

Answer (score 0):

After some correction in my code with 2-3 answers help.
The final answer is :-

```
    <?php
        $date = $record['Child']['dob'];
        $str = "+".$Vac['Vac']['time_take']." week";

        echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($str,strtotime($date)));                
   ?>
```

The output is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Its working once after concatenate the code.

```
$start_date = $record['Child']['dob'];  
$str =  $Vac['Vac']['time_take']." week";
$date = strtotime($start_date);
$date = strtotime("+".$str." week", $date);
echo date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

Output:

```
2015-01-08
```